# Sending Complex Object From Angular to SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I am having trouble sending a complex object to my SignalR hub. My JavaScript object matches exactly to my C# object, so I would expect everything to work. However, I am unable to hit my `UpdateEmployee` method. I have other methods in my hub that work just fine with simple types. Here is what I currently have implemented -

SignalR Hub

```
public void UpdateEmployee(int userId, Employee employee)
{
    // Update employee
}
```

Where `Employee` is defined as

```
public class Employee: Persistable
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Which just simply inherits `Persistable`

```
[DataContract]
public class Persistable
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to hit that method from my SignalR JavaScript client

```
$.connection.myHub.server.updateEmployee(userId, employee);
```

Where my `employee` object in JavaScript looks like

```
{ Id: 1, FirstName: "Test", LastName: "One", DateOfBirth: "01012001" }
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried it without the DateOfBirth value?

Comment: Ah! Good call. When I pass in a `null` DateTime (since it is nullable in C#) I am able to access the method. Perhaps I will just need to parse the date in JavaScript before it is passed to the hub.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the `DateOfBirth` value?

Perhaps it isn't able to bind your value `01012001` to the nullable DateTime?  I have a feeling it has to be either NULL or a bindable value, else the binding will actually fail.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case. Working on parsing out the date now.